# Function to check if input field is empty

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to validate a form field.

The function `validate_emp` checks if the input field is empty. I want to know why it's not working.

```
$first_name = $middle_name = $last_name = $gender = $email = "";
$first_nameErr = $middle_nameErr = $last_nameErr = $genderErr = $emailErr="";

function validate_emp($input_name, $error_mess, $field_name){
    if(empty($_POST[$field_name])){
        $error_mess = "This field is must not empty.";
    }else{
        $input_name = $_POST[$field_name];
    }
}

if(isset($_POST["btnregister"])){
    validate_emp($first_name, $first_nameErr, "first_name");
    validate_emp($middle_name, $middle_nameErr, "middle_name");
    validate_emp($last_name, $last_nameErr, "last_name");
    validate_emp($gender, $genderErr, "gender");
    validate_emp($email, $emailErr, "email");
}
```

This is the form that I've created

```
<form method="POST">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php echo $first_name ?>"> <span class="error"> <?php echo $first_nameErr ?> </span><br>
    Middle Name: <input type="text" name="middle_name" placeholder="Middle Name" value="<?php echo $middle_name ?>"> <span class="error"> <?php echo $middle_nameErr ?> </span><br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php echo $last_name ?>"> <span class="error"> <?php echo $last_nameErr ?> </span><br>
    <select name="gender">
        <option name="gender" value="">Gender</option>
        <option name="gender" <?php if($gender == "Male") { echo "Selected"; }?> value="Male">Male</option>
        <option name="gender" <?php if($gender == "Female") { echo "Selected"; }?> value="Female">Female</option>
    </select> <span class="error"> <?php if ($gender == "") {echo $genderErr;} ?> </span> <br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>"><span class="error"> <?php echo $emailErr ?> </span><br>
    <input type="submit" name="btnregister" value="Register">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't returned anything from the function try returning something.

```
 function validate_emp($input_name, $error_mess, $field_name){

        if(empty($_POST[$field_name])){
            $error_mess = "This field is must not empty.";
        }else{
            $input_name = $_POST[$field_name];
        }

       return // 

    }
```

Comment: `return $error_mess;
return $input_name;
return $field_name;`

Do you mean like this? 

I've already tried it and it's still not showing an error after I entered and submitted with blank fields.

Comment: if you want to show error on frontend use echo instead. return only returns the value it doesn't actually print out .

Comment: If you are trying to show errors on frontend it would be beneficial if you just pass errors into a variable and then pass the variable into frontend and then check if the variable actually exists in the frontend and then show the errors if the errors are present.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when you do:

```
    validate_emp($first_name, $first_nameErr, "first_name");
    validate_emp($middle_name, $middle_nameErr, "middle_name");
    validate_emp($last_name, $last_nameErr, "last_name");
    validate_emp($gender, $genderErr, "gender");
    validate_emp($email, $emailErr, "email");
```

the first and second parameters of the function are using variables that aren't defined.

I can see you are using them as variables by reference, and in order to do so you must use them with & before them, if I where you I would return empty or the value and evaluate that:

```
       function validate_emp($field_name){

            if(empty($_POST[$field_name])){
                $output = "";
            }else{
                $output = $_POST[$field_name];
            }
            return $output;
        }
```

Then outside of the function:

```
$first_name = validate_emp("first_name");
if ($first_name == "") { echo "$first_name cannot be empty"; }
```